# Append Content to HTML and Remove Appended Content When Click Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code allows me to append new content to the div "users". However, I want to be able remove the appended content if the user clicks button.

The current code removes only the "remove" button when its clicked. However, I need to remove the entire appended code with the class "removeuser", in the beginning of the appended code.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
<div id="users"></div>

<script>

function adduser() {

count += 1;

$('#users').append('<div id="field'+ count +'"  class="removeuser[]"><div 
id="left"><div id="fieldname">user #'+ count +' Name:</div><div 
id="field"><input id="user_name'+ count +'" name="user_name[]"' + '" 
type="text" /></input></div><div id="clear"></div></div><div id="leftleft"> 
<div id="fieldname">user #'+ count +' Age</div><div id="field"><input 
type="number" id="user_age'+ count +'" name="user_age[]" 
style="width:50px;" min="0"></input></div><div id="clear"></div><br></div> 
<div id="leftleft"><a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="adduser(); return 
false;"><div id="field" class="add"><div 
style="position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;">add another user +</div></div> 
</a><br></div> <div id="leftleft"><a href="javascript: void(0)" 
onclick="$(this).remove();" ><div id="deluser[]" class="add"><div 
style="position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;">-</div></div></a><br></div> 
<div id="clear"></div></div>');


var no = document.getElementById("deluser");

no.onclick = function(){


$('#users .removeuser').$(this).remove();

};

</script>
```

Comment: You're aware that this code would seem to create multiple `<div>` elements with the same `id` (`deluser`), which would be invalid HTML and - by design - break your JavaScript?

Comment: True, I'm not sure how to create dynamic ids and check if they've been individually clicked. I'm stumped. I've tried various methods. However, my knowledge of Javascript is minimum. Any suggestions?

Comment: var no = document.getElementById("deluser");
change this line to use dynamic element id .. like deluser1, deluser2 etc and use the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell this is might be the solution you're looking for *(note not supported in all browser. See below for transpiled version)*...

```js
var count = 0;
adduser();

function adduser() {
    $('#users').append(newUser(count))
    count++;
}

function deluser(e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.user-container').remove();
}

function newUser(count) {
     var deleteButton = `
        <div>
            <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="deluser(event); return false;">
                <div class="add delete-user" data>
                    <div style="position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;">-</div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <br>
        </div>
     `;
     return `
        <div class="user-container">
            <div id="left">
                <div class="fieldname">
                    user #${count} Name:
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input id="user_name${count}" name="user_name[]" type="text" /></input>
                </div>
                <div id="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="fieldname">
                    user #${count} Age
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="number" id="user_age${count}" name="user_age[]" style="width:50px;" min="0"></input>
                </div>
                <div id="clear"></div><br>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="adduser(); return false;">
                    <div class="field" class="add">
                        <div style="position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;">add another user +</div>
                    </div> 
                </a>
                <br>
            </div> 
            ${count > 0 ? deleteButton : ""}
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="users"></div>
```

There area quite a few things wrong with your initial attempt though and I don't mean to be rude, but you should probably do more work learning the basics of HTML, JS and in this case jQuery. [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/) is where I started out many years ago and think it is a great introduction to web development ([Treehouse - front-end web development](https://teamtreehouse.com/tracks/front-end-web-development)). That being said here are the most glaring issues...

1. Unique `id`s

   - `id` attributes must be unique per HTML document. As in, having `id="leftleft"` and then on another element in same document having `id="leftleft"` is invalid.
2. Missing closing bracket of function block `}`
3. HTML template strings

   - Honestly I don't know how you're able to read that HTML template string, but this is one of the issues front-end frameworks like [React](https://reactjs.org/) and [Angular](https://angular.io/) are meant to solve. Writing HTML templates like this will definitely introduce bugs and also drive you insane.
   - Instead or rewriting your whole program in React or Angular I would suggest using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and either using [Webpack + babel](https://medium.com/@jeffrey.allen.lewis/the-ultimate-2018-webpack-4-and-babel-setup-guide-npm-yarn-dependencies-compared-entry-points-866b577da6a) to [transpile](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them) your code  to achieve browser support or for now just visit [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl) and manually drop in your JS (with template literals) then replace with output code.

This is how the code would look after being transpiled through Babel, which would be supported in all browsers..

```js
var count = 0;
adduser();

function adduser() {
  $('#users').append(newUser(count));
  count++;
}

function deluser(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('.user-container').remove();
}

function newUser(count) {
  var deleteButton = "\n            <div>\n                <a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" onclick=\"deluser(event); return false;\">\n                    <div class=\"add delete-user\" data>\n                        <div style=\"position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;\">-</div>\n                    </div>\n                </a>\n                <br>\n            </div>\n         ";
  return "\n            <div class=\"user-container\">\n                <div id=\"left\">\n                    <div class=\"fieldname\">\n                        user #".concat(count, " Name:\n                    </div>\n                    <div class=\"field\">\n                        <input id=\"user_name").concat(count, "\" name=\"user_name[]\" type=\"text\" /></input>\n                    </div>\n                    <div id=\"clear\"></div>\n                </div>\n                <div>\n                    <div class=\"fieldname\">\n                        user #").concat(count, " Age\n                    </div>\n                    <div class=\"field\">\n                        <input type=\"number\" id=\"user_age").concat(count, "\" name=\"user_age[]\" style=\"width:50px;\" min=\"0\"></input>\n                    </div>\n                    <div id=\"clear\"></div><br>\n                </div>\n                <div>\n                    <a href=\"javascript: void(0)\" onclick=\"adduser(); return false;\">\n                        <div class=\"field\" class=\"add\">\n                            <div style=\"position:relative;left:-4px;top:1px;\">add another user +</div>\n                        </div> \n                    </a>\n                    <br>\n                </div> \n                ").concat(count > 0 ? deleteButton : "", "\n                <div class=\"clear\">\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        ");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="users"></div>
```

Comment: You should clarify that you can have multiple id attributes but they must be unique. Your wording implies only one is allowed per document.

Comment: Hey great answer! Really helped! One question will it remove all the data in the fields too when Remove Button is clicked? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Yup everything inside of the `<div class="user-container">` will be destroyed including those fields.

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much! Also, is there a way to hide the remove button for the first append only?

So the user can't remove the first fields

Comment: Sure just updated both examples. Let me know if you want anything explained.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
$( '#users' ).empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use following code

```
var no = $(".deluser"); // add class 'deluser' to each div

no.onclick = function(){
    $('#users').empty();
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I appreciate your reply. Your code works but only removes the "deluser" div. I'm trying remove everything in the #users div

Comment: Still deletes the "deluser" div only. Actually my "deluser" div is dynamic, for example it would increase by number deluser1, deluser2, etc depending on how many times the user runs the append content function.

Is there a way to retrieve the dynamic field, such as:

      var no = document.getElementById("deluser1");

Also, the "removeusers" class is dynamic and would increase each time the  append function is ran by the user, such as:
removeusers1, removeusers2, etc.

Comment: Oh ok... So, I am guessing all these dynamic elements are identical to each other in terms of stylesheets, right? If yes, you can have same class attribute value to them. That's how, 'class' is used. Class has to be common across elements, ID has to be unique. In that way, you can just delete/get the elements  by using by using class selector. e.g. `$("#users").find(".class_of_div_to_be_deleted").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to illustrate your approach in another way, I hope it will help you.

```js
var count = 0;
function addUser(i) {
  var userBloc = '<li class="list-group-item" id="user'+i+'"> I am the user'+ i +
                  ' <br><button class="btn btn-danger remove" data-count="'+i+'">Remove me</button><hr></li>';
     return userBloc;             
}

$('#add').click(function(){
  $('#blocs').append(addUser(count));
  $('#user'+count).fadeIn(activeRemove); //important to active remove event
  count++;
});

function activeRemove(){
  $.each($('button.remove'), function(i,item){
    $(item).click(function(){
        $('#user'+$(item).attr('data-count')).remove();
    });

});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blocs" class="list-group"></div>
  <button id="add">Add a another user</button>
```